# problem using unrar and adding alternative search paths

Tags: command-line

Following [this guide](http://www.reddit.com/r/PleX/comments/2pxx9e/rar2fs_install_guide_linux/), I'm stuck at `./configure`, with error saying:

```
Can't find unrar source - add alternative source search path using --with-unrar and rerun configure
```

I don't know how to make this work. I understand I need to add a source path containing .rar files but I don't know how to use this.

Answer (score 0):

The asnswer is for the @enberg guy from https://gist.github.com/enberg/84710b619bdb0b10e945. He made a script to install it.

```
#!/bin/bash
WORKDIR=`mktemp -d` && cd $WORKDIR

# Get deps
sudo apt-get -q update
sudo apt-get -qy install make libfuse-dev g++

# Get, make and install unrar
wget http://www.rarlab.com/rar/unrarsrc-5.1.1.tar.gz
tar zxvf unrarsrc-5.1.1.tar.gz
cd unrar
make && sudo make install
make lib && sudo make install-lib
cd ..

# Get, make and install rar2fs
wget https://googledrive.com/host/0B-2uEqYiZg3zR1F0b0tmRktiaXc -O rar2fs-1.20.0.tar.gz
tar zxvf rar2fs-1.20.0.tar.gz
cd rar2fs-1.20.0
./configure --with-unrar=../unrar --with-unrar-lib=/usr/lib/
make && sudo make install

# Cleanup
rm -rf $WORKDIR
```

give an execute permission

```
chmod +x install_rar2fs_ubuntu.sh
```

Then run the script from your terminal

```
sudo ./install_rar2fs_ubuntu.sh
```